# Value of the dual variables corresponding to data points on the margin in Support Vector Machine

Tags: classification, svm, regression-coefficients

Consider the setting of binary classification using soft-margin SVM.

\begin{align*}
\min_{w,b,\xi} ~~ &\lambda ||w||^2 + \sum_{i=1}^m \xi_i \\
\text{s.t. } \quad &y_i(w\cdot x_i + b) \geq 1 - \xi_i ~~ \forall i = 1,\ldots, m \\
&\xi_i \geq 0~~ \forall i = 1,\ldots, m 
\end{align*}

Can anybody give pointers to show that " if some data point $x_i$ is on the correct margin , then the corresponding dual variable i.e. $\alpha_i \in (0,1)$" ?
More clearly, how to prove that the above said $\alpha_i$ will never take the boundary value $0$ or $1$ ?

Comment: Please provide a source/link to the origin of your information.

Comment: The dual variable will be zero, if the constraint is not binding thus the datapoint $i$ associated with the dual variable $a_i$ does not influence the position of the decision plane (=is not a support vector). Therefore I do not understand the question.